# Rounded box-shadow on square box

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, dropshadow

With this:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000
}
```

I get a rectangle with drop shadow. See https://jsfiddle.net/df9dfev5/ The problem is that the shadow has rounded corners. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Less blur and lighter color maybe like this

https://jsfiddle.net/df9dfev5/3/

```
 div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #666;
}
```

Look at this article http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/df9dfev5/1/

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #000;
}
```

The third 0 is the blur radius. When it's low, the box-shadow isn't blurred as much.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you `box-shadow: -2px -1px 15px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);`

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/df9dfev5/2/

Comment: Why the downvote? it works. Because of making black grey using alpha? Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to assess first what you want the drop shadow to look like, where the light should be coming from, etc. Then you can determine what your values need to be.

Instead of using your blur value to lighten the shadow color, you can change the color value itself. Knowing you don't want to have a unrealistic overly rounded shadow, means you will have to use your offset values and this is why it's important to determine where the light is coming from.

Here's my take on this: https://jsfiddle.net/df9dfev5/6/

```
div {
     width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: green;
     box-shadow: 3px 6px 2px #bbb
 }
```

I've chosen to have my light source come from the upper left, mostly from the top, so I have offset the shadow to the right by `3px` and down by `6px`. A `2px` blur accounts for some of the diffuse look of the shadow and the color `#bbb`, a light gray, does the rest.